# Is it possible to manipulate the graph loaded in memory by Giraph?

Tags: memory, distributed, distributed-computing, graph-databases, giraph

I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095959/gremlin-giraph-graphx-on-titandb) that Giraph is a graph analysis framework, but is it anyway possible to add, remove or update the nodes & edges of the graph loaded in memory by Giraph?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Giraph provides APIs to add/remove vertex/edge into/from the underlying graph while the computation are running.